# Find the increasing segment of function $y = -2 \sin x$

Tags: functions

Hello I have the following question,

> Given the function $y = -2 \sin x$. We have to find in which segment of the graph the function is increasing.

Normally I would choose from $(-\frac{π}{2}; \frac{π}{2})$, but the answer to this question was from $(\frac{5π}{4};\frac{3π}{2})$.

Can someone explain why ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What were the choices?

Comment: Have you got the question right? $-2\sin x$ is *decreasing* on the interval from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.

Comment: Are you still here, Sviatoslav?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum points of your function are $2k\pi +3\pi/2$ where the function takes the value of $2$ and the minimum points are at $2k\pi+\pi/2$ where the function takes the value of $-2$

Thus on the interval $(\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$ your function increases and this repeats periodically with period $2\pi$

Comment: So you're suggesting that OP's answer and the answer OP cites from unspecified sources are both wrong. Could be, or could be that OP has just miscopied the problem.

Comment: That is what I get from my calculations of derivatives and I think the graph will support my solution as well.

Comment: I am not denying the correctness of your mathematics. I'm pointing out that the question you are answering might not be the one OP was asked.

Comment: The function $y=-2\sin x$ is decreasing on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ despite the OP's claim. The interval $(\frac {5π}{4};\frac{3π}{2})$ is part of the solution but not the whole interval of increase.

Comment: I know that, in fact, I wrote exactly that in my comment on the question. That's why I think maybe OP got the *question* wrong, rather than getting the *answer* wrong.

Comment: I agree. The OP may have had the problem wrong.